# City break during 6h transit in Delhi

Tags: transit, india, airport-security, delhi

My international flight should land at 8:05 at Delhi on Sunday and my domestic flight is scheduled at 14:30. I would like to visit the city as 6 hour seems like lots of time. I dont need to check in or hand over luggae. I just need to get through security there and back. Am I naive? Does it make sense? When shall I arrive to Delhi to get back through the security?

Comment: Allowing for getting off the plane, clearing Immigration, then back through security and getting to the gate before closure, I don’t think you actually have 6 hours. Where exactly ‘in the city’ would you like to visit? https://theculturetrip.com/asia/india/articles/what-to-do-on-a-layover-in-delhi-india

Comment: I know that many hours would be lost. If I had one or two hours in the city for a walk or visit some tourist spots, it would be nice. But I have no idea, if it is possible. DEL is a very busy airport. Shall I expect long queues? I definitively don't want to risk my connecting flight.